# Create a GPU enabled container in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, tensorflow

I'm new to docker and I am trying to run tensorflow within a GPU enabled docker container. I have successfully followed this guide: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/docker. I understand that when I want to run a gpu enabled container i have to add the `--gpus all` argument to the run command like so: `run --gpus all tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu`. I'm wondering however if there is a way I can create a Dockerfile that builds an image that already has gpu support enabled and the `--gpus all` argument can be omitted from the run command. Or can I pass this as an argument to docker build rather than docker run

Comment: There are a fairly large number of options that must be given at the `docker run` command line and can't be defaulted in the Dockerfile.  Since `docker run --gpus` regulates access to host hardware it doesn't surprise me that there's no way to set this in a Dockerfile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this for my specific use case. I was trying to set up a Docker container to work with VS Code. However VS code has the concept of "dev containers". To create/use a dev container you must create a `devcontainer.json` file. In it you can specify `runargs` and add the key: value of

```
"runArgs": ["--gpus","all"]
```